# Wrong sorting in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, sorting

I use many HQL queries with "order by" clause in my application. When I am getting the results (using query.list()) they are sorted wrongly - letters are positioned before numbers. So for example instead of:

```
AG1
AG2
AGA
AGB
```

there is:

```
AGA
AGB
AG1
AG2
```

When I try to run the equvalent SQL queries in SQL Developer the returned results are in the correct order.

I suspect there is something wrong with configuration as the problem appears in all HQL queries, but I don't know what it may be. I would be grateful for some suggestions.

I am using Oracle 11g and Hibernate 3.3.2.GA (I know it's old but it is a version I need to use because of some internal dependences).

Comment: You can perform it Using the Sort annotation , two things to remember:

1.Add the Sort annotation to the Set to sort.
2.Implement a Comparator that will be used for the sort.